# Android storing current activity's context only in a static variable, will it cause memory leak?

Tags: android, memory-leaks, android-lifecycle, android-context

If I have a static Context variable in a class and whenever any class oncreate gets invoked I assign that variable current activity context.

Now I want to ask will this architecture creates memory leaks or not, because as I am always storing current activity's context so as we will not be storing context of activity class which got destroyed so I don't think there will be any memory leak.

Comment: In general, storing an `Activity` in a static field is risky and should be avoided. Moreover, it is never needed -- there is always a better solution that can avoid it.

Comment: @CommonsWare yes I know, thanks for telling, I just wanted to ask will there be any memory leak? Also as previous activity gets destroyed now can garbage collector destroy this activity safely or not?

Comment: "I just wanted to ask will there be any memory leak?" -- you have not provided a [mcve] showing what you are doing.

Comment: @CommonsWare I am thinking of a case where by storing only current activiy's context i can call that activity's method, and for that I need to store current activity's context.

Comment: @CommonsWare Like I have a class A which contains methods which all activity's want to invoke and when that class get the response then it need to send the response back to that called class.